# Pyodbc SQL Server stored procedure with params works on local machine but not on server

Tags: python, sql-server, stored-procedures, pyodbc

I have the following Python code (version 3.8.1). This works fine on my local machine using VS Code terminal. However if I copy the script to a server and then execute it, the execute command returns nothing, no errors.

If I replace the stored procedure call with a single select statement, then it works. What am I doing wrong? I have executed the stored procedure with different parameters to see whether it returns any records and the procedure works. Also I have `set count on` in my procedure. The account used is a `db_owner` and has execute permissions on the the procedure.

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};Server=myserver;Database=db_name;uid=xxx;pwd=yyy')
cursor = conn.cursor()
conn.autocommit = True
params = ( id, del_flag )
sql = "{CALL dbo.proc_name (?,?)}"   # works locally, does not work on server
#sql = """\
#EXEC dbo.proc_name @c_id=?, @delete_flag=?  # works locally, does not work on server
#"""
#sql = "select top 1 * from table_name;" # works locally and on server

cursor.execute(sql,params)
rows = cursor.fetchall()
print(rows)
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason that I do not understand the procedure call was not accepting the params in the below format.

```
params = ( id, del_flag )
sql = "{ call dbo.proc_name (?,?) }"
cursor.execute(sql,params)
```

I had to change the above 3 lines to a single statement like this

```
cursor.execute("{ call dbo.proc_name("+id+","+del_flag+") }")
```